# C - strtok give back less data

Tags: c, string, strtok

```
char line[81] = "$11,$10,1";
token = strtok(line, " \t\v,$");
token = strtok(NULL, ",");

printf("%s\n",token );  // its $10 from the previous strtok 

if(strstr (token, "$") != NULL){
token = strtok(NULL, "$");
printf("%s\n",token );  // I want to print 10 but it prints 1.
}
```

I'm trying to remove one char with strtok. However as you can see it give back only one digit.

Comment: Show the initial call to strtok, and some code.

Comment: Can you describe the issue in more details? you have char* token = "$10"?

Comment: The output looks correct to me.  What is the expected output?

Comment: @DietrichEpp I'm trying to print just 10.

Comment: @roshinc: if you want to remove the `'$'` from the token you already have, then you'll need to work with the pointer already in `token`.  Calling `strtok()` again with a `NULL` argument gets the next token from the original string - it doesn't do anything with the last token retrieved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want `10` as a result then I think what you are looking for is

```
char line[81] = "$11,$10,1";
token = strtok(line, " \t\v,$");
token = strtok(NULL, ",");

if(*token == '$')
    printf("%s\n", token + 1); 
else
    ... do something else ...
```

After all you have already got your token, there is no use looking for more.

As @Dietrich said, the output looks correct.  Let me break it down for you.

```
char line[81] = "$11,$10,1";
token = strtok(line, " \t\v,$");
```

This eats ignores the initial "$" (because its a delimiter) and returns "11".

```
token = strtok(NULL, ",");   
printf("%s\n",token );  // its $10 from the previous strtok
```

The `strtok` eats the "," and returns "$10".  It also seems to eat the following
"," -- that behaviour is allowed but not required by the man page that I am reading.

```
if(strstr (token, "$") != NULL){
    token = strtok(NULL, "$");
```

The remaining string is non-empty, but has no more "$"-delimters.  Thus this `strtok` will return the whole remainder, that is "1".

Comment: Thanks @adrian-ratnapala .I see what I did wrong. And your code give me what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Change `token = strtok(NULL, ",");` to `token = strtok(NULL, "$,");`

Answer (score 0):

So I'm trying to follow it:

```
char line[81] = "$11,$10,1";
token = strtok(line, " \t\v,$");
```

you'd might expect it to return "\0" while in the buffer there is "11,$10,1"
but - it returns "11" while in the buffer there is "$10,1", since it will not have an empty buffer to return

```
token = strtok(NULL, ",");
```

returns "$10" while in the buffer there is "1"

```
printf("%s\n",token );  // its $10 from the previous strtok 
token = strtok(NULL, "$");
```

returns "1" while in the buffer there is "\0", since there's no separator
    printf("%s\n",token );  // it prints 1 but not 0.